# How can I repeat chart four times?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I need on my website four charts from chars.js library
At the moment there code for one chart

```
   $(function () {
   $(".chart").drawDoughnutChart([
          {value: volume, color: "#2980b9", text: volume},
          {value: rest, color: "#d2d4d8", text: volume},
    ]);
          volume = volume - 10; // For TEST filling
          rest = rest + 10; // For TEST filling 
   });

(function ($, undefined) {
            $.fn.drawDoughnutChart = function (data, options) {
                var $this = this,
                        W = $this.width(),
                        H = $this.height(),
//other property include text under one chart
```

Should I repeat above methods  3 times more for each chart or how is  best way seen?
Thanks :)

Comment: try to give each chart the .chart class?

Comment: If it's the same chart, just [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/) the container (`<div>` containing the chart)

Comment: I tryed, but shoud I repeat also second function?